# Will Window mobile device automatic cut off curent when fully charged

Tags: windows-mobile

Good day.

I know that Android device will automatic cut off current when it is fully charged. How about window mobile device? Does it have the similar mechanism as Android?

Is there any way I can do like changing the registry to change the minimum and maximum of battery level to start/stop charging?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no registry key to control the current flowing from a charger in a Windows Mobile device.

Charging modern batteries is a complex technique. Normally the external adapter delivers 5V via an USB connector. The charging circuit inside the phone will watch the batterie voltage and supplies more or less current to the battery. So, in regards of the current flowing, the device will 'cut-down' the flow down to a minimum level or even shut off the current when the battery is fully charged. But the batterie will be checked periodically and so the charge current may be increased after some time.

So, what is the real intention for your question?